# C++11 : How to use std::mem_fn and std::bind with inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, bind, member

I need to have the ability to have a Base class that can store pointers to member functions not only for its own methods but also for subclasses.  Here is an example of what I want USING LAMBDAS, but I would like to be able to do it with MEMBER FUNCTIONS:

```
struct Base
{
    void registerFunc(std::string const& name, std::function<void *(void *)> code)
    { 
        functionTable_[name] = code; 
    }

    void *invokeFunc(std::string const& name, void *arg)
    {
        auto x = functionTable_[name];
        auto func = std::bind(x, _1);
        return func(arg);
    }

    Base()
    {
        registerFunc("hello", [this](void *arg) { printf("hello"); return nullptr; });
        invokeFunc("hello");
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void *(void *)>> functionTable_;
};  

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived()
    {
        registerFunc("world", [this] (void *arg) { printf("world"); return nullptr; });
        invokeFunc("world");
    }

    // Instead of lambdas, I would like to be able to put member
    // functions like this into the std::unordered_map of the Base class
    void *memberFunc(void *arg) { printf("oyoyoy"; }
};
```

Comment: I don't see a virtual function in your base class. Are you trying to use polymorphism?

Comment: No I am not trying to use polymorphism -- although the purpose of the functionTable_ is very similar to a v-table I know.  Think about the case where a piece of data received over the wire causes one of the functions ("hello" or "world") to be executed.  You can't use the v-table for that, you basically have to build your own.

Comment: Are you looking for the syntax `registerFunc("world", std::bind(&Derived::memberFunc, this, _1));`? Unrelated, your `invokeFunc` is a bit labored and could simply be `return functionTable_[name](arg);`.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is explained here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions

Comment: @Casey - your answer worked!  Pls submit as a solution and I'll check the box to give you credit.  Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasBenard, I did see that page but the thing that Casey pointer out was the std::bind applied to the member function pointer.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `invokeFunc` method does not need to use `std::bind()` and should at least check if function is there:

```
void *invokeFunc(std::string const& name, void *arg)
{
    auto &x = functionTable_[name];
    if( !x ) return 0;
    return x(arg);
}
```

But better would be to use `std::map::find()` I believe

Second you can use `std::bind()` to pass method:

```
Derived()
{
    registerFunc("world", [this] (void *arg) { printf("world"); return nullptr; });
    invokeFunc("world");
    registerFunc("method", std::bind( &Derived::memberFunc, this, _1 ) ) );
    invokeFunc("method");
}
```